# Error in ampscript syntax

Tags: salesforce, ampscript

Please help me figure out the problem in my ampscript.

So here it is:

```
%%[ Var @phone Set @phone = Lookup(“Support Phone Numbers”, “Phone”, “Locale”, "%%Opportunity:Account:Locale__c%%") ]%%
```

The result of the script is placed in email like this:

```
%%=v(@phone)=%%
```

But when I try to preview the email I get this error:

> There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative.
>    Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid
>    An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail.
>    Script Expression: Lookup(“Support Phone Numbers”, “Phone”, “Locale”, "%%Opportunity:Account:Locale__c%%")
>    MemberID: 7295734
>    JobID: 0
>
> The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client.
>    Function Call: Lookup(“Support Phone Numbers”, “Phone”, “Locale”, "%%Opportunity:Account:Locale__c%%")
>    Attribute or Field Name: “Support
>
> Invalid Content: 
>    Set @phone = Lookup(&#“;Support Phone Numbers&#”;, &#“;Phone&#”;, &#“;Locale&#”;, "%%Opportunity:Account:Locale__c%%")

Here are the screenshots:
[template code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JKdd.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGgDy.png)

Comment: Have you tried it without the quotes on Opportunity:Account:Locale__c? I don't think you need the wrapping %% either.

Comment: Thanks for help. Here is how it must be:
Lookup("Support Phone Numbers","Phone","Locale",[Opportunity:Account:Locale__c])

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be caused by the 2 different styles of double quotes (") being utilized within the function.

For instance:

```
Lookup(“Support Phone Numbers”, “Phone”, “Locale”, "%%Opportunity:Account:Locale__c%%")
```

Should look like:

```
Lookup("Support Phone Numbers", "Phone", "Locale", "%%Opportunity:Account:Locale__c%%")
```

Also there is the was a problem with %% wrapping for Opportunity:Account:Locale__c

Finally the script should look like this:

```
Lookup("Support Phone Numbers","Phone","Locale",[Opportunity:Account:Locale__c])
```

Thanks.